# How to search by meta property in kibana

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, elastic-stack

[image]

Given this image, how could I filter responses such that I only receive results where 'meta.fred' is equal to 'jackson' ?

Have been poking around docs/testing but haven't been able to find an answer, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can type `meta.fred: jackson` in the search input box.

Entry doc for basic queries and filters: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/beats/packetbeat/current/_kibana_queries_and_filters.html